# What is a community post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Hi, I wonder what is the difference to put a post as a community post and not to mark the option of community post.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find this answer in the **[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)**: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)